# 2 Array combine into one array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is two array one is firstName another is lastName

```
{
  firstName: ['name1', 'name2'],
  lastName: ['last1', 'last2'],
}
```

but I want to formate the data into one array like this.

```
{
  "name": [{
      "firstName": "name1",
      "lastName": "last1"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "name2",
      "lastName": "last2"
    },

  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map):

```js
const getNameObj = (data = {}) => {
  const { firstName = [], lastName = [] } = data;
  if(firstName.length !== lastName.length) return;
  const name = firstName.map((fn, i) => (
    { firstName: fn, lastName: lastName[i] }
  ));
  return { name };
};

console.log( 
  getNameObj({ firstName: [ 'name1', 'name2' ], lastName: [ 'last1', 'last2' ] })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through it using `for...in` and push each element inside new `array` like this example

```js
const data = {
 firstName: [ 'name1', 'name2' ],
 lastName: [ 'last1', 'last2' ],
}

let newData = [];

for (let el in data.firstName){
  newData.push({
    firstName: data.firstName[el],
    lastName: data.lastName[el],
  })  
}

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the result.

```js
const input = {
    firstName: [ 'name1', 'name2' ],
    lastName: [ 'last1', 'last2' ],
};

const result = input.firstName.reduce((acc, firstName, index) => {
   acc.name.push({
     firstName: firstName,
     lastName: input.lastName[index]
   })
   return acc
}, {'name': []})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a new object `{name: <value>}`, and set your `<value>` to a mapped version of the `firstName` array, where each firstName from your array is mapped to an object of the form `{firstName: ..., lastName: ...}`. Here the `firstName` key has a value that is the current name, and the `lastName` key has a value from the `lastName` array at the corresponding index:

```js
const obj = { firstName: ['name1', 'name2'], lastName: ['last1', 'last2'], };

const res = {
  name: obj.firstName.map((firstName, i) => ({firstName, lastName: obj.lastName[i]}))
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```js
let obj = {firstName: ['name1', 'name2'],lastName: ['last1', 'last2']};
let finalObj = {};
finalObj.name = []
for (let i = 0; i < obj.firstName.length; i++)
      finalObj.name.push(
          {
            firstName: obj.firstName[i],
            lastName: obj.lastName[i]
          }
      )
```